# Empty browser screen with python cgi

Tags: python, cgi, real-time, flush

i need to display dynamic data in a graph in real time. 
And so i need to draw a new graph with updated data every second.

The problem is that i cannot empty the previous output in the browser
and so instead of getting a simple graph with the updated data 
i get lots of graphs

here is the code. currently it has random data

```
def graph(data):
    X,Y = 500, 275 #image width and height
    img = Image.new("RGB", (X,Y), "#FFFFFF")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    #draw some axes and markers
    for i in range(X/10):
        draw.line((i*10+30, Y-15, i*10+30, 20), fill="#DDD")
        if i % 5 == 0:
            draw.text((i*10+15, Y-15), `i*10`, fill="#000")
    for j in range(1,Y/10-2):
        draw.text((0,Y-15-j*10), `j*10`, fill="#000")
    draw.line((20,Y-19,X,Y-19), fill="#000")
    draw.line((19,20,19,Y-18), fill="#000")

    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        draw.line((i+20,Y-20,i+20,Y-20-data[i]), fill="#000")

    rtime = str(time.time())
    img.save("../images/out.png"+rtime, "PNG")

    htmlBody = []
    htmlBody.insert(0, 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n') 
    htmlBody.append('<html>')    
    htmlBody.append('<body>')    
    htmlBody.append('<img src=\"../images/out.png'+rtime+'\" alt=\"\" />')

    htmlBody.append("</body>")
    htmlBody.append('</html>')  
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write('\n'.join(htmlBody))
    sys.stdout.flush()





data = []
if (printgraph!=None):
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = oldsysout
    for i in range(1,5):
        data.append(int(250*(random.random())))
        graph(data)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate CGI script for creating the image.  You can then reference the new script in the image tag.  `src="makepic.py"`.

Follow [this guide](http://lost-theory.org/python/randomimg.html) for making a Python script serve a dynamic image.  On the page, you can use JavaScript's `settimeout` to refresh the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about a page with an HTTP "Refresh" header on it. The content of the header should be two items separated by a semicolon. The first would be 2 (the number of seconds after which to refresh) and the second would be the URL of the page (since you want to content to repeat). You can also use the META tag to inject a pseudo-header from your page content, should you desire.

Unfortunately this would mean some re-organization of your back end, because the page now has to deliver a representation of the current state of the computation each time it is called. This won't necessarily be easy.

To create a page where the server can just "push" new content whenever it wants, you will need to do a little programming. Consider delivering a stream of scripts that set a DIV's InnerHTML attribute to the HTML for the next graph, rather than just delivering pure HTML. Then have your page request this content. This has the further advantage that the page won't be completely refreshed each time the new graphic is delivered.